# What is the difference between undermine and weaken in this context? ( undermine/weaken a basic principle)

Tags: differences, semantics

When do we use **undermine** instead of **weaken**?

For instance, why is it:

> The simplicity of the trick **undermines** a basic principle of
>   photography, that the camera cannot lie.

... and not "**weakens** a basic principle"?

From my research we can conclude that they have pretty similar meanings:

- [undermine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/undermine)
- [weaken](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weaken)

Comment: 'undermines' doesn't sound right to me either, do you have more context? What is the trick it refers to?

Answer (score 1):

Neither *undermine* nor *weakens* is suitable in this context.  a *principle* relates to what ought to happen.  The belief that the cannot lie has been **refuted** by the fact that the camera actually can lie.

Well, that’s not quite right either.  It was a metaphor at most.  We believed that **the person with a camera** could not  lie (misrepresent reality).  That turns out not to be true.  So the belief/claim has been disproved.

For this reason, the principle that it is safe for police, juries, voters, news editors and policy makers to  place special reliance on photographic evidence has been undermined.

The difference between *undermine* and *weaken* here is small but significant.  *Undermine* carries a suggestion that the thing being undermined (in this case the evidential value of photographs) is worth having, so that its weakening would be a loss.

So I agree that the statement is imprecise in its phrasing, but in its use of the word *principle* rather than of the word *undermine*.

Answer (score 1):

"Undermine" and "weaken" are two different things.

To "undermine" is to literally or figuratively remove the foundation of the thing discussed.

To "weaken" is to somehow reduce the strength of the thing discussed.

But neither is relevant since "The camera cannot lie" has never been a "basic principle of photography", so there's nothing to undermine or weaken.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *undermine* is occasionally stronger than *weaken*.

If a policy has a 90 percent approval rating, and an action causes that rating to drop to 80 percent, the approval has been *weakened*, but probably not *undermined*.

To my mind, *undermining* something results in the thing being unstable, or collapsing - as if a mine had been dug under its foundations.

*Weakening* something may or may not make the thing unstable. Something strong that is weakened might still be strong, just less so.

As for this specific usage, what might it mean to weaken a principle?

A principle is

> a fundamental truth or proposition that serves as the foundation for a system of belief or behaviour or for a chain of reasoning (*[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/principle)*)

Can we weaken a fundamental truth? A truth is binary: it's true or it's false. Our faith in a truth can weaken.  We can decide that a principle is not true, but if so, the principle is destroyed, not weakened. It is no longer a principle. It doesn't make sense to talk about a weak principle.

On the other hand, to undermine a principle would mean to make the principle - the "foundation for the system" - collapse.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is to be mentioned that I am not a native speaker in English. Exactly that could be the reason why I know this specific example.

Right now I am preparing for a CAE exam, i.e. a Certificate of Advanced English exam for foreign learners of the English language.

"But the simplicity of the trick UNDERMINES a basic principle of photography, that the camera cannot lie" is the correct one of 4 options in a test, according to the Cambridge University Press and the Cambridge English Language Assessment. The remaining 3 options are WEAKENS, DEMOLISHES, and DISMANTLES.

In my opinion, to demolish and to dismantle both mean to destroy sth. in a mere physical way, while to weaken means to lose strength.

I believe that a principle cannot be weakened, but either work or not instead. A physical destruction of a principle is also not possible. To my mind, that seems to be the reason why undermine is the correct solution.

According to the Cambridge Online Dictionaries, to undermine itself has 2 meanings - on the one hand to weaken, and on the other to destroy. These meanings are not reduced to mere physical aspects. As a consequence, they can also be used figuratively.

In the example mentioned above, the figurative meaning of to destroy a principle should be the key to this problem. The background of the story in the CAE test is that 2 ladies intentionally modified a photograph of a garden setting in a way that one could see fairies on that picture. A kind of deception towards those who have a look at the photo, which may prove that to undermine is a way of deliberately doing sth in this connection.